# OS X mysql cannot connect ERROR 2002 (HY000) after installing pear package. Using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, macos, osx-mavericks, pear

I installed the PEAR ImageGraph module as follows:

`pear install Image_Graph-alpha`

This command came from the [github](https://github.com/pear/Image_Graph/tree/master/docs) page

Now when I try to connect to MySql I get the following message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I am using XAMPP and OS X Mavericks.

Any advice? I would hate to have to reinstall everything.

Comment: You pinpointing at the correlation between pear installing something and this error is mind-boggling to me. I did pear install something like one week ago and I do have the same issue now. How did you install mysql (I did via the dmg on mysql's site) ? And did you try switching your mysql connection from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` (this trick worked for me) ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I googled the error 2002 mysql.sock' (2) and got all sorts of different answers but none worked. So that is about how far I went.

Comment: MYSQL came with xampp but this installion was in 2013. It was working yesterday but today after the install it broke.

Comment: May sound like a stupid question but : Did you recently did an OS X update ?

Comment: Actually yes! That might be it.

Comment: Ahah ! I had the same ! Apple did an update of their version of PHP. So they also did an override of the apache conf and maybe your php version used is back to the stock one (where the definition of the mysql.sock is empty) and not mamp's one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75606/discussion-between-b-enoit-be-and-topdizel).

Comment: Have you fixed yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally determined that the update to OS X was what broke MySql and prevented me from connecting to MySql. Had to backup files and then reinstall MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how there can be any link between installing ImageGraph and you suddenly not being able to connect to MySQL.

**Judging from your question, it seems that you did not make any project specific changes, perhaps you did some system upgrades recently? That would more easily explain the sudden inability to connect.**

Speaking of mysql and upgrades, you should be using the mysqli or pdo extensions as the [original] mysql one is deprecated and support for it may be removed in PHP7. More information on this can be read on [the PHP The Right Way site](http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension). If you do this now you should have fewer surprises later on.